# tx_seo: divide sitemap in serveral

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

**Divide a sitemap into several sitemaps**

The sitepackage (Branch: 1.0.3) is published by Github: 
https://github.com/Epoche-Napoleon/epochenapoleon_sitepackage

I have a "small" website with several thousand pages in the page tree. Now I'm trying to render a Sitemap via tx_seo.

When I call these via domain.tld/sitemap.xml I run into a timeout with the following feedback:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is unable to service your request due to downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            epochenapoleon {
                pages {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\PagesXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        excludeDoktypes = 9818, 9819, 1789, 654, 656, 7076
                        additionalWhere = no_index = 0
                    }
                }
                news {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        table = news_table
                        sortField = sorting
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
                        pid = 25,26
                        url {
                            pageId = 28
                            fieldToParameterMap {
                                uid = tx_extension_pi1[news]
                            }
                            additionalGetParameters {
                            tx_extension_pi1.controller = News
                            tx_extension_pi1.action = detail
                            }
                            useCacheHash = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

When I call the sitemap via domain.tld/?Type=1533906435 he shows me a list with five entries:

- [domain.tld/sitemap.xml?sitemap=pages&cHash=e4ec46f1edda9255c833d8f327921c95](https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml?sitemap=pages&cHash=e4ec46f1edda9255c833d8f327921c95)
- [domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=1&sitemap=pages&cHash=76bbdc5117a27bf2b2818c00cc443831](https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=1&sitemap=pages&cHash=76bbdc5117a27bf2b2818c00cc443831)
- [domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=2&sitemap=pages&cHash=d2af230407bb97a452c005a68ec97e6d](https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=2&sitemap=pages&cHash=d2af230407bb97a452c005a68ec97e6d)
- [domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=3&sitemap=pages&cHash=d3f2fb99e60e0337b375b023425f106f](https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=3&sitemap=pages&cHash=d3f2fb99e60e0337b375b023425f106f)
- [domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=4&sitemap=pages&cHash=a87d1658708f8d86dca8509fe0605](https://www.domain.tld/sitemap.xml?page=4&sitemap=pages&cHash=a87d1658708f8d86dca8509fe0605)

Here are probably for the first pages in the page tree individual Sitemaps are generated. UID=2 is, for example, a folder.

How can I now create a sensible multi-part sitemap that lets me start a new sitemap from individual nodes I've chosen?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use `epochenapoleon` after xmlSitemap - but `sitemaps` should be the key.

Comment: Hello @develth, thank you for your feedback.
In the meantime, I have removed my own configuration for tx_seo and now use only the default configuration of tx_seo.

However, the result is the same. As a result, I get the links described below.

Comment: I looked again at the standard configuration. There are under
plugin.tx_seo.config.xmlsitemaps.pages.config.excludedDoktypes = 3, 4, 6, 7, 199, 254, 255 listed. However, the output pages in the sitemap already contain three folders (ID = 2, ID = 3 & ID = 4).  
Of course, the only correct page (ID = 1) will also be displayed.

Comment: Do you have a URL to check your generated Sitemap? And are the missing pages not the page types you exclude?

Comment: When i use the settings within my pages, i get a sitemap with just one link -  domain.tld/sitemap.xml?sitemap=pages&cHash=xxx - when opening this, all pages are listed.

Comment: You can find the sitemap at http://p521482.mittwaldserver.info.  

Currently I have deleted my own configuration and replaced it with the default configuration of tx_seo. The behavior is the same.

He always shows me the links described above, even though ID = 1 is the page type 254.

Are there possibly EXT: who do not work with tx_seo? The system was not rebuilt but hoisted from TYPO3 8.7 to 9.5.

Comment: Seems fine for me. It generate multiple links to the final sitemap (pagination), caused by your amount of pages.

Comment: Just checked the source - it makes a fix pagination when there are more than 1000 pages. So each 1000 pages get an own pages sitemap, that´s why you get this list

Comment: Thx @develth After deinstall tue seo Extension cs_seo and install it Magazin the sitemap works very fine.